# Bash script to check for directory name with condition

Tags: linux, bash

I want to exclude some directory in my script (directory name >1000) for deletion and here is my directory look like:

```
/home/tester/100
/home/tester/1000
/home/tester/1020  # delete all files inside
/home/tester/2000  # delete all files inside
```

My bash script:

```
cd /home/tester
for dir in */ ; do
   echo -n $dir": ";
   find "$dir" -type f | wc -l;
   if [ $dir -gt 1000 ]; then
      cd $dir;
      rm *;
      cd ..;
   fi
done
```

I got error on the *if* line and have no idea how to fix it ...  Is it possible to do with bash script ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the error message you get? Are you certain all of the directories in `/home/tester` have names consisting of only digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for dir in */ ; do` will set `dir` to things like "1000/" -- and the "/" makes it not a valid number. You can trim off the trailing "/" with `${dir%/}`. I'd also recommend double-quoting it to prevent possible weird parsing:

```
if [ "${dir%/}" -gt 1000 ]; then
```

Note that if the directory name isn't a number (even after the "/" is removed), you'll get an error from the comparison, and the `then` clause won't run (which is probably what you want). If you want to handle other (non-numeric) directory names more gracefully, you should add some appropriate is-this-a-number test first.

Also, using `cd` in scripts tends to be problematic, because if a `cd` fails for any reason, the rest of the script will continue running, but in the wrong place. This can cause all sorts of chaos. Consider what'd happen if one of the `cd $dir` commands fails: it'd run `rm *` in the /home/tester directory, deleting all the non-subdirectory files there, then it'd `cd ..`, leaving it in /home. The next iteration would try to `cd` down to something like 2000, which doesn't exist under /home, so that `cd` would fail too, and then it'd delete all files in /home. This repeats indefinitely, potentially all the way up to running `rm *` in /, the root directory. Not good at all.

I recommend either putting error checks on `cd` commands, or just avoiding them entirely in favor of using explicit paths to files.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/tester || {
    echo "Couldn't cd to /home/tester, quitting here..." >&2
    exit 1
}

for dir in */ ; do
   echo -n "$dir: "
   find "$dir" -type f | wc -l
   if [ "${dir%/}" -gt 1000 ]; then
      rm "$dir"/*    # Explicit path -- the / is redundant, but won't hurt
   fi
done
```

I've also added an explicit shebang line, double-quoted all the variable references (good general scripting hygiene), and removed the semicolons from the ends of lines (not needed in shell syntax).

Another recommendation: run your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll point out a lot of common mistakes like unquoted variable references and unchecked `cd`s.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$dir` is not numeric. Add `set -x` at the to of your script to debug.

Use `"$(basename "$dir")"` to get the numeric value.

Comment: Specifically, the trailing `/` will still be there.

Comment: @ceving Sorry, I am new to bash.  I don't understand where to put the [tag:set -x] and [tag:"$(basename "$dir")"]

Answer (score 0):

When I did not have my first cup of coffee, I would do

```
for dir in */ ; do
   echo -n $dir": ";
   find "$dir" -type f | wc -l;
done

mv /home/tester/1000 /home/tester/some_unique_name
rm /home/tester/[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/*  
mv /home/tester/some_unique_name /home/tester/1000
```

This will not work when you have directories > 9999.
Perhaps `rm /home/tester/[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*/*` will work, when you don't have directories like `1000backup` or `2000my_unique_name`.

A better solution is

```
find . -regextype sed -regex '/home/tester/[0-9]\{4,\}' ! -name 1000 | 
   xargs -L1 -I{} echo rm {}/*
```